my program still does not recognize txtFechaDev, even though I have the jcalendar 1.4 library
is my first time here, i have a problem in this program, I download the jcalendar 1.4 but the problem is in textFechaDev, it seems that the program txtFechaDev is not declared or there is an error in the same library,I don't know what else I could do in the video that I downloaded, the program works without errors, does anyone know if it could be an error coming from another part of the java project?, here is a part of the code:

package Views;

import Models.Autor;
import Models.AutorDao;
import Models.Combo;
import Models.Editorial;
import Models.EditorialDao;
import Models.Empresa;
import Models.Estudiantes;
import Models.EstudiantesDao;
import Models.Libros;
import Models.LibrosDao;
import Models.Materias;
import Models.MateriasDao;
import Models.Prestamos;
import Models.PrestamosDao;
import Models.Usuarios;
import Models.UsuariosDao;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.autocomplete.AutoCompleteDecorator;

public final class FrmPanel extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    
    Usuarios user = new Usuarios();
    UsuariosDao usuarioDao = new UsuariosDao();
    Editorial editorial = new Editorial();
    EditorialDao editorialDao = new EditorialDao();
    Autor autor = new Autor();
    AutorDao autorDao = new AutorDao();
    Materias materia = new Materias();
    MateriasDao materiaDao = new MateriasDao();
    Estudiantes estudiante = new Estudiantes();
    EstudiantesDao estudianteDao = new EstudiantesDao();
    Libros libro = new Libros();
    LibrosDao libroDao = new LibrosDao();
    Prestamos prestamo = new Prestamos();
    PrestamosDao prestamoDao = new PrestamosDao();
    DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
    

    public FrmPanel(String user) {
        initComponents();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jTabbedPane1.setSelectedIndex(6);
        jTabbedPane1.setEnabledAt(0, false);
        jTabbedPane1.setEnabledAt(1, false);
        jTabbedPane1.setEnabledAt(2, false);
        jTabbedPane1.setEnabledAt(3, false);
        jTabbedPane1.setEnabledAt(4, false);
        jTabbedPane1.setEnabledAt(5, false);
        jTabbedPane1.setEnabledAt(6, false);
        jTabbedPane1.setEnabledAt(7, false);
        txtIdAutor.setVisible(false);
        txtIdEditorial.setVisible(false);
        txtIdEmpresa.setVisible(false);
        txtIdEst.setVisible(false);
        txtIdLibro.setVisible(false);
        txtIdMateria.setVisible(false);
        txtIdUser.setVisible(false);
        txtIdPrestamo.setVisible(false);
        txtIdLAutor.setVisible(false);
        txtIdLEdi.setVisible(false);
        txtIdLMat.setVisible(false);
        MenuPrestamo.setEnabled(false);
        cbxEstudiante.removeAllItems();
        cbxLibros.removeAllItems();
        llenarEstudiante();
        llenarLibros();
        AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(cbxEstudiante);
        AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(cbxLibros);
        LimpiarTable();
        ListarPrestamo();
        Calendar c2 = new GregorianCalendar();
        txtFechaDev.setCalendar(c2);
    }


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the
How to Ask page for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to
reproduce the issue. See also How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

I don't see the import for the jcalendar.jar. Something like this should be in your class imports list: import com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser; When you declare your date chooser to add to your Form is should be something like this: JDateChooser txtFechaDev = new JDateChooser(); myJFrame.getContentPane().add(txtFechaDev);. Make sure you have properly added the jcalendar.jar file to your project.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
